# Getting internet to Linux VM without being detected by Network

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vmware, tunneling

I'm trying to get internet to a Linux VM (Backtrack 5 on VMWare Workstation). Unfortunately I was told to not "bridge" the connection from the VM because it could be detected by our companies network admins.

Our company has a firewall and proxies for normal web browsing. I can get around it by ssh tunneling to a linux server ([putty + ssh](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/93106-escaping-the-firewall-with-an-ssh-tunnel-socks-proxy-and-putty))

Is there a way I can get my Linux VM to have internet connection via SSH/Putty tunneling without it being detected on our corporate network? I'm not sure if I need to bridge my VM and change some settings on the Linux VM or if I need to alter VMWare somehow to grant internet to VMs via tunneling...?

Would appreciate any areas topics I should read into or any lead I can take to get accomplish this.

Comment: "circumvention of security or policy" is explicitly forbidden in the Serverfault FAQ. I wonder if it's accepted here. [I have asked for clarification on meta](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/circumvention-of-security-or-policy).

Comment: I'm not circumventing security or policy, we're working on a work around on this internally because it's holding our team back.. but till then we're pursuing alternatives

Comment: Why do you care about the admins noticing it then?

Comment: Because the admins noticing it means a box that they (the admins) have not protected (scanned, installed anti-v, etc) is on the network which would not be cool with them. An alternative soln is for us getting an external internet connection (which we're looking at).. but i'm thinking there must be a way to get internet to the VMs without making them active nodes on the network (my guess)

Comment: @Mat Nonsense. Please keep it technical, don't prevent people from answering on-topic questions due to your mistaken sense of propriety.

Comment: I'm sorry that your question was closed, [it should not have been](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/circumvention-of-security-or-policy/1282#1282). It should be reopened soon.

Comment: I tried to get more info from SE about this, but haven't heard back. For the moment I'm going to say it's fine as long as the question isn't illegal, so I reopened it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek If you want a precedent, questions about jailbreaking are welcome on [apple.se] and [android.se], with SE's blessing, as are questions about [DRM removal](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212/is-discussion-of-techniques-for-removing-drm-permitted) on [su]. This question doesn't even involve anything that might be on shaky legal ground or at risk of any DMCA takedown, so why would SE care at all?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to achieve this. When using a SOCKS5 proxy  (SSH Tunnel) you actually still leak some information. SSH is a stateful protocol which uses TCP, however DNS requests use the UDP protocol (stateless) which can't be sent over the SSH tunnel. I did a blog post on this once which you can find [here](http://cloud101.eu/blog/2012/03/01/proxify-your-traffic-through-an-ssh-tunnel/).

There are also other ways like tunneling over DNS (which is unreliable and extremely slow). However do note that circumventing policy can make you liable if your tunnel is responsible for breaching or introducing malicious programs/users into your corporate network environment. There is a reason why your admins wouldn't be *cool with it*.

Answer (score 0):

While we wait for the clock to tick down on whether this is deleted, I will say this: If your client has an X11 display, you can do regular X11 forwarding over it. If not (probably not, since you're using Putty/Windows) you can try installing [xming](http://www.geo.mtu.edu/geoschem/docs/putty_install.html) and configure PuTTY to X11 forward to your local XMing server.

Once you do that, you can run firefox or chrome on the remote machine. Just make sure you've enabled compression on the PuTTY and server side, otherwise there can be quite a bit of lag, especially over slower links.